# What Other TFS clients exist?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

Team explorer is a real pain to use for some simple tasks, and is very slow. I'd like another solution to access my TFS repository.
I really like SvnBridge, but I cannot attach a TFS work item when I check-in with tortoise.

Does somebody know some alternatives ?

***Update***

From what I've seen, the integration of TFS with the windows Explorer with TFS Powertools requires that you run on an account with the same name as your login on TFS, too bad...

Comment: While the Team Explorer UI is surely far from perfect, I'm curious what scenarios it's slower than SvnBridge.

Comment: @Richard Berg, for example when I close my visual studio without closing Team explorer, it tries to connect to TFS when I restart VS, so it slows down the boot, then it shows two times a login popup even if I don't want to connect. This afternoon I've lost 1 hour because I've changed the mapping of my workspace with my repository, but my projects binding didn't update (The only solution was to delete the workspace and recreate it).Than, it makes my file Read only, so I have problem with deployements item of my tests. Then when I make a change to a file without VS, good luck to check-in changes

Comment: I hate team explorer, but I love the work items feature, so I search a solution with the best of both world.

Comment: @Slashene - see here: http://blogs.msdn.com/hippietim/archive/2006/03/14/551320.aspx  If you change workspace mappings, project bindings shouldn't change unless you've done strange things to alter the relative paths between them.  Just make sure you do a Get after changing mappings (VS should prompt you if you have 2008 SP1).

Comment: AutoLoadServer doesn't exist in my registry :(

Comment: So create it :)  Make sure you are under the VisualStudio\9.0 tree (not 8.0) if you have 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the cross platform [Teamprise Explorer client](http://www.teamprise.com/products/explorer/).

Answer (score 2):

TFS Power tools integrates with windows explorer and it works kinda like TortoiseSVN. On this way you can check-in/out, get latest etc. from windows explorer

Answer (score 1):

There's a command-line tool (tf.exe) that I believe is part of the product. There's another available through the [TFS Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx).